# Concise check if variable is object but not an Array or a Date

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

You can check it this way:

```
if (typeof var == 'object' && !Array.isArray(var) && !(var instanceof Date)){
 ...
}
```

But is there a more concise way?

**Edit**

I should disambiguate the question: by object I don't mean only a literal object but any object (also an instance of a class)

Comment: write a utility function?

Comment: `var.constructor.name`?

Comment: I added a note to clarify that by object I don't meant only "literal objects", object is also the result of new Something(), right?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `i.constructor === Object`:

```js
console.log(
    [{}, new Date(), []].map((i) => i.constructor === Object)
)
```

Comment: `class A{}; console.log( (new A()).constructor === Object )` will produce `false`.